# Getting a form to submit when the enter key is pressed when there is no submit button

Tags: html

I've got a form that has no submit button and it would be great if the form is still submitted when the user hits the enter key.  I've tried adding a hidden submit button, which gives me the desired behavior in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, but the form is still not submitted in IE.  Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you have no submit button? This is bad usability. I guess that a lot users will be confused and won't know what to do. The problem is that you are doing something unexpected. The user expects that every form has at least some kind of submit button. Don't forget: **Don't surprise the user**.

Comment: @Felix We have an href wrapped by a div that defines the button so that we could style it as we wanted.  So visually, there is a submit button, but there isn't an input tag with the "submit" type in the form.  Would you say that this is the wrong approach?

Comment: Ah I see, I understand *submit button* in a wider sense ;). No, I guess that is perfectly fine, as long as you clearly show that this the button/link to submit the form. I would design it that it looks like a button (at least not like a standard link).

Comment: — style a real button instead of trying to simulate one with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested/cross-browser:

```
function submitOnEnter(e) {
    var theEvent = e || window.event;
    if(theEvent.keyCode == 13) {
        this.submit;
    }
    return true;
}
document.getElementById("myForm").onkeypress = function(e) { return submitOnEnter(e); }

<form id="myForm">
<input type="text"/>
...
</form>
```

If there is no submit button, the form will degrade miserably if javascript is not available!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `*on*keypress`?

Comment: @Andy E - Thanks, indeed it should, fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery (naturally):

```
$("#myForm input").keyup(
    function(event){
        if(event.keycode == 13){
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    }
);
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Forms are usually submit (on Windows, anyway) when the enter key is pressed down, not lifted up.

Comment: I went with this answer, but it ought to be event.keyCode

Answer (score 0):

onKeyDown event of textbox or some control call a javascript function and add form.submit(); statement to the function.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
document.myformname.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will require JavaScript. The easiest way to implement this with JavaScript if you don't know the language would be to use something like jQuery (much like what inkedmn said).

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    <!--
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keycode == 13){ // This checks that it was the Enter key
                    $("#myForm").submit(); // #myForm should match the form's id attribute
                }
            });
        });
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
    ...
    </form>
</body>
```

For more information on jQuery:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#jQuery:_The_Basics

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can just put a `<button type="submit">submit</button>` there and change his position with css, right? `position:absolute;left:-9999px;` Should do the trick. `display:none` will not work tho.

This will also work if js is not loaded.

edit:
However, if you chose to use js, do not forget to not submit if you have a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

This may be accomplished cross-browser by keeping the submit input intact and some creative CSS. By keeping the input available, you also preserve support for screen readers.

```css
    .no-submit-button {
      position: relative;
    }

    .hidden-submit {
      border: 0;
      clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
    }
```

```html
    <form class="no-submit-button">
      <input class="hidden-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```