# Hiding an HTML Form's Submit Button

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a form to submit when the enter key is pressed when there is no submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271464/getting-a-form-to-submit-when-the-enter-key-is-pressed-when-there-is-no-submit-b)

I'm trying to implement a text input box with an invisible submit feature. As such, the field has no submit button attached and is submitted when the "enter" key is pressed.

Here's an example of how I want the code to function:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/"><p>

<input class="text_input" type="text" value="SEARCH: type &amp; hit Enter" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if 
(this.value == 'SEARCH: type &amp; hit Enter') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') 
{this.value = 'SEARCH: type &amp; hit Enter';}" />

<input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" value="" /></p></form>
```

Here's the code I can't get to work:

```
<p>Have us call you. Input your number:</p>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10" size="10">
<input type="submit" value="Click-to-Call"  onclick="window.open('http://secure.ifbyphone.com/clickto_status.php?click_id=34124&phone_to_call=' + getElementById('phone').value + '&key=asdfjknj3459dj38sdka92bva', 'Clickto' , 'width=200,height=200,toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, copyhistory=no,resizable=no')">
```

I've tried adding the form attribute with a GET request to the URL in the "onclick" portion to no avail.

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: I'm confused. If you dont want a submit button, why not just leave out the submit.

Comment: The example code works. It looks like your code is implemented on the onclick of the submit button, do you want it to happen to the onblur of the input box?

Comment: If I remove the submit here, then the code in the "onclick" portion won't exist (which is needed).

Comment: I suppose, I'm not familiar with "onblur". Would that allow me to preserve functionality and have only the text box (no submit button)?

Comment: @TrentScott you can put javascript in the form tag with `onsubmit=""` and it will execute when the form submits

Comment: @MrGlass Thanks for the tip. Putting the JS in the input box's [code]onsubmit=""[/code] didn't work, but it did work in the [code]onblur=""[/code]. While working, however, it doesn't work when Enter is pressed, only when the user clicks out of the input box.

Comment: @TrentScott thats because onBlur is triggered when the user leaves the input. Not sure what you need to do on the form submit, but this tutorial might be helpful: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html

Comment: Thanks! I need to run this code on submit:

window.open('http://secure.ifbyphone.com/clickto_status.php?click_id=34124&phone_to_call=' + getElementById('phone').value + '&key=asdfjknj3459dj38sdka92bva', 'Clickto' , 'width=200,height=200,toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, copyhistory=no,resizable=no'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add  this to your css regarding ID searchsubmit:

```
    #searchsubmit
    {    
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

The button will still work but will not be visible.
The enter action should work by default if the form's input is focused/used.

---

The onBlur function could be triggering the actions you want to. onBlur occurs when the user leaves the input field (clicking away)

You could try using JQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('form').each(function() {
    $('input').keypress(function(e) {
        // Enter pressed?
        if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
        }
    });

    $('input[type=submit]').hide();
});
```

});

This will trigger the onSubmit event of your form, but you could change

```
this.form.submit
```

for

```
$('#phone').blur()
```

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

---

Try adding a javascript script block with this:

```
   document.getElementsById('phone')[0].onkeydown= function(event)
{
    if (event == undefined)
    {    
        event = window.event;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var js_phone = document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value;
        window.location = 'myPage.php?phone='+js_phone;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave the CSS a shot but the form no longer submits. I'll try adding the jQuery.

Comment: I just modified the answer, in case you want to trigger the onBlur event (where your JS code could be). I'll stay tuned.

Comment: Hmm... Added the jQuery and it still only submits when the user clicks out of the input box, not when they press Enter. Tried putting the required JS in "onsubmit" and using "this.form.submit" and putting it in "onblur" and using "$('#phone').blur()", respectively.  Demo: http://rainleader.com/

Comment: take a look at my last edit. This SHOULD work. Sorry for the wrong solutions sir.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here's the code I implemented: https://gist.github.com/3130342

Still not behaving correctly. Did I format the "window.location" string correctly?

Comment: I even tried changing the value of `window.location` to `http://google.com` and it does't seem to like it. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

To hide something, you could use the following code:

```
input[type=submit]
{
    display:hidden;
}
```

The `input[type=submit]` is just there as an example, replace it with selector for you submit button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding that disables the functionality to have the field submitted when "Enter" is pressed. I thought that would work too...

Comment: Oh dear. Edited post, could you try `display:hidden`? Either that or you could use an event listener to submit the form via javascript to mimic the effect.

Comment: I tried `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`. Both removed the button, but lost the submit-on-enter functionality, too. Any other ideas? Here's a demo: http://rainleader.com (it's in the right sidebar).

Comment: You seem to have done it with the search box, so you try that